# Python-Selenium table-scraper only returns first row

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, html-table, html-tbody

I'm trying to extract information from a table with selenium.

I got the rows:

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr')
```

And I'm trying to get two specific cells within the row:

```
for r in rows:
    diccionario["property1"] = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
    diccionario["property2"] = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text

with open("bbdd.json", "a", encoding="utf-8") as bd:
    json.dump(diccionario, bd, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

However, it will only return the information from the first row (repeated as many times as the number of rows)

Is there a way to "force" the code to find the elements within the row we're currently iterating in the for loop?

**Code**

All the trs (rows) code look the same.

The tds/cells that I need are the first two (the classes look the same for every td in the different rows as well).

[image]

Comment: difficult to help you without the url or html code

Comment: @Frenchy I'll edit the question and provide the html, as it's impossible to access to the website unless you have an account (it requires a couple of days to register...)

Comment: This means that we can't reproduce the issue and can't really help you. In any case you could try loading the table with `pandas`: `df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)`, then export the table to [json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I understand it tho. I'll try to find a way to index the "children" of the rows in some way and work around that. Thanks a lot tho!

Comment: we dont know the value of xpath in loop

Comment: is suggest you to copy all table from inspect and copy the hml code..not picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was focused on trying to access the cell itself. However, I changed my mind and tried to reach the content from the "webelement parent" (the row itself).

The row's text property had the information that I needed.

The only problem was that I had to parse some text (not that hard to do). So in the end I didn't need to access the different tds.